# Get course's courseWork

Tags: php, google-classroom

I am trying to get courseWork of a particular course, and create courseWork for the course, using PHP.

I can get the courses like this:

> ```
> $results = $service->courses->listCourses($optParams);
> ```

But I am not able to get the course work. I tried:

> ```
> $results = $service->courses->courseWork->listCourseWork(array('courseId'=>123));
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This is what ended up working for me.

> $results = $service->courses_courseWork->listCoursesCourseWork($id);